# How to add overlay text on google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google maps in my android app with markers and a I added a circle around the marker using addCircle() function. But I also want to add text near the circle. Is there any way to add text at a particular position?

Image of where I needed text on map is below:
[image: valid HTML]

Comment: What about using built-in title function? For instance:

`googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(bitmapImage).title("text"));`

Comment: @Javanshir I want to add text near the circle and not the marker.

Comment: some visual representation along with code would give us a head start

Comment: @Coder I did attach a screenshot as you asked. Please check it. And I did not find any code of how to write text on maps

Comment: share the code you have so far for the circle and marker. I am not a CSS and script pro but will give a try. Hopefully there are many good people here who are willing to help